# Attempting to create Set Game in Java

Tags: java, constructor

So for a project for school I have to create a Set Game. (setgame.com if you are unfamiliar with the game like I am) I am having an incredibly difficult time starting the project. First off I need to have a "four parameter constructor" (not entirely sure what this is) and each parameter has three possible "choices". So my questions to help get me started are, is my four parameter constructor set up properly, and if so how do I get my constructor to recognize and pick one of the three choices. Again I am not asking how to do the entire project, I just need a little guidance as to how to set it up. What I have written so far is

```
public class SetCard{

private String color;
private String symbol;
private int number;
private String shading;

//What I think a four parameter constructor may look like.
public SetCard(String color, String symbol, int number, String Shading){
    //not sure how to get each choice to select one of the three choices.
    color = ("red" || "green" || "purple");
    symbol =  ("oval" || "squiggle" || "diamond");
    number = (1 || 2 || 3);
    shading =  ("solid" || "open" || "lined");
}
```

Obviously this does not work, as BlueJ does not allow me to compile. I was thinking maybe doing an if, else-if, else with Math.random to assign a choice to each variable. So example for color I would do something like (Math.random * 3) + 1 to get the range of 1-3. Then say if(1) then red, else if(2) then green, else purple. Again this is just me guessing at what exactly I am to do so I can make it pick one of the three choices, however I do not know exactly if this is the proper way to do it, or if there is a more efficient way. This is my first Java class and I have no prior coding experience, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learning is about trying. Why not try your idea. StackOverflow is for diagnosing and solving programming error not designing project solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your on the right track.  That is a 4 parameter constructor.

Where you're off is needing to randomly assign each variable.  Sounds like your assignment is just to create a constructor that makes a card when you pass 4 arguments into it.  Your goal is to be able to do this:

```
SetCard card1=new SetCard("red", "oval", 3, "lined");
```

Which will create a new card that is red, oval, 3, and lined.

A few tips:

Call your class Card, not setCard.  setCard implies an action, or verb, what you are creating is an object, or noun.

You are going to need to use the this. command in your constructor.  You'll figure it out why with a simple google search.

Shading is miscapitalized in your constructor parameter.

I'm sure assigning the card random properties is going to be your next task, not this one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been struggling for the past 3 hours. If I could vote your answer a million times I would! Thank you and have a great weekend!

Comment: No problem, and I'm not sure why so many are so quick to down vote a simple question...Glad to help.